# The ? expression in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm taking a introduction course in Java and I have a question about the `?` expression (I've done some C# programming) but I'm not that familiar with it there either.

If I have this if statement, how do I use the `?` on it? I have a task where I'm supposed to compare three variables in different ways and I hate to have alot of if statements.

```
    //Task b (If var3 is divisible with var2)
    if(var3 % var2 == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("\n" + var3 + " is divisible with " + var2);
        System.out.println(var3 + " divided with " + var2 + " is: " + var3 / var2);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("\n" + var3 + " is not divisible with " + var2);
    }
```

This just look messy.. It's okay to turn it in like this but I personally think it look awful.

Comment: No, it doesn't look messy.

Comment: Why do you think using the ternary operator would make this look less messy?

Comment: This sounds a bit like an XY Problem. Do you actually want to avoid long chains of if statements? It honestly sounds like what you're really looking for is a `switch`

Comment: I think it looks ok. If you use the terny operator `?` it will be bad readable. The terny operator sould only be used in very short terms.

Comment: @MarounMaroun When you have 7 ones that look almost exactly the same I think it does.

Jens Alright. Thank you. Ill stick to what I have then.

Comment: @Fredrik Then `?` won't help you here. Consider arrays and loops.

Comment: It would be useful if you would show a situation which is *actually* a problem then, instead of one that isn't.

Answer (score 2):

You could use it like so:

```
bool isDivisible = var3 % var2 == 0;

System.out.format("\n%d is %sdivisible with %d",
                   var3,
                   isDivisible ? "" : "not ",
                   var2);
if (isDivisible) {
    System.out.format(" %d divided with %d is %d", var3, var2, var3 / var2);
}
```

I'm using it to inject the word "not" where required, so that the first two statements are now combined. Note use of `format` as string concatenation gets ugly quickly.

Comment: Sorry, edited (and rolled back) the answer because didn't realize `printf()` actually calls `format()`.

Comment: That's OK `printf` probably more readable actually. Though OP: you should consider also `System.out.println(String.format(...))` as will add new line characters for you.

Comment: @weston I prefer the simpler `%n` for a new line, e.g., `System.out.format("this %d and that %d%n", 1, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

`?` is not complete, it is a group of `? :` termed as ternary operator. Basically the syntax is as follows:

```
<variable> = <condition> ? <true value> : <false value>;
```

So your code goes like this:

```
String msg = 0 == var3 % var2 ?
            "\n" + var3 + " is divisible with " + var2 :
            "\n" + var3 + " is not divisible with " + var2;
System.out.println(msg);
```

You could also use `()` to avoid confusion:

```
String msg = (0 == var3 % var2) ?
                ("\n" + var3 + " is divisible with " + var2) :
                ("\n" + var3 + " is not divisible with " + var2);
System.out.println(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called ternary operator. It can be used to evaluate logical expression in a statement.Its syntax is

> [condition] ? [true expression] : [false expression]

In your code example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int var3 = 12;
    int var2= 6;
    System.out.println( var3%var2==0 ? "divisible" : "not divisible" );   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks ok as is. If you only printed one line in each case you could replace  the if/else block with:

```
System.out.println("\n" + var3 + " is "
                        + (var3 % var2 == 0 ? "" : " not ")
                        + " divisible with " + var2);
```

But since you need to print 2 lines in one case and only one in the other case your if/else construct is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ternary operator can be used for simple one-liners, not for more elaborate code:

```
System.out.println(var3 % var2 == 0
    ? "\n" + var3 + " is divisible with " + var2 + "\n" + var3 + " divided with " + var2 + " is: " + var3 / var2
    : "\n" + var3 + " is not divisible with " + var2);
```

Not a lot better is it?

Most solutions offered here strike me as a case of, what I call, 'over-automating'.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
String text1 =  "\n" + var3 + " is divisible with " + var2 + "\n" + var3 + " divided with " + var2 + " is: " + var3 / var2;
String text2 =  "\n" + var3 + " is not divisible with " + var2;   
String res = var3 % var2 == 0 ? text1 : text2;
    System.out.println(res);
```